# How to create a multi line chart in d3.js where each line's data is pulled from a seperate csv?

Tags: javascript, python, csv, d3.js, plot

I am aiming to create a simple multi line chart using d3.js, something like the following in nature:

https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-multi-line-chart

I have found several great examples that show how to do this where all the data is in a single CSV. One of these examples is this one:

http://bl.ocks.org/asielen/44ffca2877d0132572cb

I have a slightly more obscure use cases requirement though. I have a directory in my project root called "data" and within this folder there is an arbitrary number of csvs. So my project folder is something like this:

```
project_root/
    index.html
    data/
        csv1.csv
        abc2.csv
        meow.csv
            .
            .
            .
        woof.csv
```

Each of these csvs have the data for a single line I would like to plot on the chart. Each csv also has the following columns:

```
str(representing a datetime)    int    float    int    string    float
```

The only columns I care about for making the chart are the first two, where:

1. the first column is a string that is a datetime. this represents the X coordinates of each point on the line. I suppose this will need to be converted from string to unix time to get easily plotable X values.
2. the second column in as int and represents the Y coordinates of each point on the line.

So taking the first two columns from a single row in the csv gives us a single (x,y) coordinate from a single line to plot via d3.js. And a single csv gives us all the (X,Y)coordinates of a single line to plot via d3.js.

I have managed to do this (sloppily) using python and matplotlib but can't directly translate this into d3 as i am very new to it. This is my python implementation if it helps or anyone is curious:

https://pastebin.com/9Eu9nwzp

If anyone can give some insight or a brief (hopefully) snippet that can accomplish this charting task in d3.js for a html document that would be lovely.

Comment: my first advice is to follow a programming course and a python one after that, SO is not porting service. Your first task is to implement a file-list request on the server

Comment: i figured out how to do this, but needed to parse the csvs into one json object to be read by d3